# DateTime in model is in US format when doing HTTPGET, but not on HTTPPOST

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

As a test, I set a model with a DateTime theDate and a String theString, and set them both to DateTime.Today in the Index method on the controller. Then return the View and the Model.

Then have a view with 2 Text controls for the @model, they are both shown as 04/07/2011  (correct for UK). If I then use a submit button to do a  HTTPGET , theDate has 07/04/2011 and the theString has 04/07/2011. if I do a POST, then both dates are the same  04/07/2011.

I have checked the CurrentCulture and CurrentUICulture, and this happens when both are en-GB.

Any ideas, as I really want to do a GET, as a POST causes issues when using Back button

I have seen http://weblogs.asp.net/melvynharbour/archive/2008/11/21/mvc-modelbinder-and-localization.aspx , but that did not fix my problem.

Some dates might be a 'Post' and some a 'Get', and this is causing the date to switch from GB to US, and I don't know how to differentiate.

Comment: Have you tried adding a `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{0:dd/mm/yyyy}")]` attribute to the date property?

Comment: I have the same problem (but with pt-PT instead of en-UK) and "DisplayFormat" did not solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Search(string Dob)
{
    DateTime DobDT = Dob == null ? null : (DateTime?)DateTime.Parse(Dob);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, this is not a forum, this is a Q&A site. Please don't post questions as answers, but you seemed to have fixed it by editing in an answer.